# In laravel, I am getting the view of current user as a follower of itself instead of followers

Tags: laravel-5

In database i have following structure

```
id | following_id | followed_id
1  |     3        |    1
2  |     2        |    1
```

I have user model and it looks like this

public function userFollows()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Diskourse\Models\User','followers','following_id','followed_id');

```
}

public function userIsFollowed()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Diskourse\Models\User','followers','followed_id','following_id');
}

public function followers()
{
   return $this->userIsFollowed->merge($this->userFollows);
}
```

And at last view looks like this

`<h4>Followers</h4>

            @if(!$user->followers()->count())

            <p>No followers</p>

            @endif
                @foreach($user->followers() as $follower)

                    @include('user/partials/userblock')

                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>`

If its working it should display user 3 and 2 as a follower of 1. Instead current user profile block is displaying twice. Please Help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the `userblock` partial looking for the variable `$user`? because that is still set to the current user.  I would use this:

```
@each('user.partials.userblock', $user->userFollows, 'user')
```

That will repeat the `userblock` view for each follower, passing the follower in as `$user`

Comment: Error occurred saying "Relationship method must return an object of type " while using $user->followers as $follower

Comment: Why are you merging the followers and the userIsFollowed collections in your `followers()` relation?  OK see edit, I didn't understand your relations well, using `userFollows` should work

Comment: ok i have modified relationship from above to this 
public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Diskourse\Models\User', 'followers', 'follow_id', 'user_id')->get();
    }     still i am facing the same problem

Comment: please post the code for `'user/partials/userblock'`

Comment: `<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $user->username]) }}">
      <img class="media-object" src="{{ $user->getAvatarUrl() }}" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $user->username]}}">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
     @if($user->location)

      {{ $user->location}}

     @endif
  </div>
    </div>`